# How to know whether previous downloaded offline map exist in device HERE SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I'm downloading heremap for a specified area using 
`MapDataPrefetcher.getInstance().fetchMapData(bbox);`

download progress and status can listen through `MapDataPrefetcher.Listener`

But I want to know whether the offline map has downloaded or not at a later time without listening to a callback.

Is there any function provided for the status of the offline map? whether it is downloaded or not?

For downloading map data I'm using the following code for downloading map data

```java
    GeoCoordinate coordinate = new GeoCoordinate(10.261258, 76.367549);
    GeoCoordinate coordinate2 = new GeoCoordinate(8.574647, 76.850176);
    GeoBoundingBox bbox = new GeoBoundingBox(coordinate, coordinate2);

    MapDataPrefetcher.Request fetchRequest =MapDataPrefetcher.getInstance().fetchMapData(bbox);
    MapDataPrefetcher.getInstance().addListener(mapDataPrefetcherListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a dedicated API for such case. You can try to download same data again based on requestId and listen for SUCCESS status which should be returned right away if the data is already pre-fetched.